# iterate through multiples of 3 with nested for loop

Tags: c#

I have a nested for loop in which 'j' represents the line number and 'i' represents the multiples of 3 below 1000.

I want it to display the line number then the multiple. For example:

```
1 3
2 6
3 9
4 12
...
333 999
```

right through to multiple 999

but it just dosent display the right line numbers and the multiples keep looping until the line numbers reach 999

```
Console.BufferHeight = 4000;
for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
{
    for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j + " " + i);                   
    }      
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i = 1, j = 3; j < 1000; i++, j += 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", i.ToString(), j.ToString()));
}
```

It will print starting at

```
1 - 3
2 - 6
```

up to

```
332 - 996
333 - 999
```

Comment: Thankyou. The of the nested for loop works logically for me but it obviously dosent in reality. why is that?

Comment: Because it performs whole inner `for` loop iteration (1000 iterations) for every one outer loop step. That makes the `Console.WirteLine` execute 1000*1000 times. I'm sure it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: what does Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", i.ToString(), j.ToString())); do?

Comment: `String.Format` replaces `{0}/{1}/{2}/...` with values passed as arguments, starting from the one after pattern string. You should use it instead of string concatenation. Read more about [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need nested loops for this problem? A single should be enough, if I understand your right.

```
Console.BufferHeight = 4000;
for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(j + " " + (j * 3));                         
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what OP's looking for? *right through to multiple 999* part is quite confusing, but I think your loop condition is wrong and OP is looking for `333 - 999` as the last line printed.

Comment: This will print the following as the last pair: `999 2997`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek and mikhairu: You both are right. If '999 2997' should be the last line th condition should be 'j*3 < 1000' or 'j < 334'

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loop for that. You can just use following code.

```
Console.BufferHeight = 4000;
for (int j = 1; j < 1000; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j + " " + j*3);      
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do something like this, or did I miss the point entirely?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", i, (i * 3)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're looping from i = 3 to i = 999 inside of a loop from j = 1 to j = 999.  This will result in 995,004 lines being written tot he console.

You want something like this:

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i )
{
   Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}", i, i * 3 );
}
```